# The Story of a horseman who rushed to arrive in the court and Big Ben clock rang 13 times

Tags: identification-request

Long time ago an old man told us a story, but I couldn't remember it very well—so I'm just wondering what was the exact story he told us.

It was about a court process where somebody was judged. And another man, woke up in the night, took his horse and rushed to the court building where the process was going.

Somehow... because the Big Ben tower rang 13 times that midnight, the man that was judged was saved. I'm not sure what was the role of the horseman... but I just remember him as part of the story.

What was this story and which is its source?

---

I tried looking on the internet and I found this, asking a similar question (however, I don't remember the old man mentioning the rifle...):

> [image]
>
> [Source](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/526713.html)

Comment: And what were the answers to that question?

Comment: He was probably telling you some version of [this old legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_stroke_of_the_clock#Culture). However your question is off topic on this site, which is for science fiction an fantasy.

Comment: @Valorum The answer was pointing to a movie which seemed unrelated to the story I heard.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Literature.SE is a possible migration target for this question, but before I migrate this can you confirm that it was a work of literature? You said you were "told" the story so I'm not sure if it's a work of literature from your description.

Comment: @Null To be honest, what user14111 suggested seems to be the closest version to what I heard. As far I remember, the old man said it's *a story*. The version I heard contained a horseman who woke up and arrived in the court and perhaps approved that he also heard the clock ringing 13 times, hence the person was saved—something like that.

Comment: Dunno about horsemen, but there's the story of [Hatfield and St Paul's Cathedral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_stroke_of_the_clock#Culture).

Comment: Being *triskaidekaphobic* I'm superstitious about answering this query.